# PHP Array - Too many levels

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to build a PHP session array in a nice clean format and I just can't seem to get it.

Here is my code:

```
$user_id = ($_GET['user_id']);
$user_name = ($_GET['user_name']);

if (!isset($_SESSION['people'])) {
    $_SESSION['people']=array();
} 

$_SESSION['people'][$user_id]=array();
$people[$user_id]['id'] = $user_id;
$people[$user_id]['name'] = $user_name;
array_push($_SESSION['people'][$user_id],$people);
```

This is my desired output:

```
Array
(
    [people] => Array
        (
            [32] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 32
                    [name] => Jane Doe
                )
        )

)
```

But this is what the code above is giving me:

```
Array
(
    [people] => Array
           (
        [32] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [32] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 32
                                [name] => Jane Doe
                            )

                    )

            )

        )

)
```

So what I'm getting back is the extra [0] and the extra [32].  I'm trying to get this for that the keys are the user_id's so I can grab values when I want them and use them for things like removal from the session.

I've tried building the hierarchy in various combinations, but can't seem to crack this one.

Note that this is for a shopping cart type thing.  I'm using push so I can continually add more to the list.

Comment: This would still push the array with a different key than the one he wanted, @Lawrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, why are you using the parentheses around the $_GET['user_id'] ?

But to help you, those additional IDs in the array were caused by the fact that you were pushing the array with a key 32 (the id of the user) to the session[people] array for the key of the user, that basically created another array in between.
To simplify the process and allow you to have it accessible by the user_id, you can simply do the following:

```
<?php
$user_id   = ($_GET['user_id']);
$user_name = ($_GET['user_name']);

if (!isset($_SESSION['people'])) {
    $_SESSION['people'] = array();
} 

$_SESSION['people'][$user_id] = [
    'id'       => $user_id,
    'name'     => $user_name
];
```

This way you are directly assigning the user data to the SESSION with user_id as the key and there is no need for pushing :)

Answer (score 1):

You create the same array twice (userid) and then push them together.

```
$_SESSION['people'][$user_id]=array(); // first time
$people[$user_id]['id'] = $user_id;// second time.
```

Then you push them together. Create it once only then push.

```
$_SESSION['people'][$user_id]=array();
$people['id'] = $user_id;
$people['name'] = $user_name;
array_push($_SESSION['people'][$user_id],$people);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your array push by this and you are good to go.

```
$_SESSION['people'][$user_id] = $people[$user_id];
```

Array push does exactly what it says, it pushes (read append) something into an existing array. And in that case you were pushing an array indexed by the user_id again.